# I want something between a controlled and an uncontrolled component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange, controlled-component

I have an input field in React.

```
<input 
    type = "number"
    value = {this.props.answer || undefined}
    onKeyUp = {(e) => (e.keyCode === 13) ? onAnswer(e.target.value) : false }
/>
```

This way it behaves just like I need it to behave:

- If there is no `this.props.answer` there is no inital value in the input.
- User can input any number. Nothing happens on `onChange`
- Once user presses Enter, the state changes (in the `onAnswer` function). After this, the value of the input field stays `this.props.answer` and the user can NOT change the value any more.

But when the user presses Enter I get this warning:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled.

I read about uncontrolled components and I tried this:

```
<input 
    type = "number"
    defaultValue = {this.props.answer || undefined}
    ref={this.input}
    onKeyUp = {(e) => (e.keyCode === 13) ? onAnswer(e.target.value) : false }
/>
```

This way I doesn't get the warning but the input field remains editable after the user presses Enter. I also tried using both `value` and `defaultValue` properties but then again I get the same warning.

I want the input field to be sort of controlled but I don't want to change the state on `onChange` but only when user presses Enter (`onKeyUp`). After this, the user should not be able to edit the input. Is there a way to implement this behavior?

UPDATE: I wasn't aware that I can set the `readOnly` property of the input based on the state. Setting it to false after setting the state solves my problem.

Comment: If you don't want the user to be able to edit the value, then shouldn't you toggle the `disabled` or `readonly` state instead?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Can you take a step back and explain?  Do you want to make the form read-only once submitted?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I didn't know about `readonly`. It just solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @DavinTryon It's not really a form just an input field but yes, I need to make it read only after user presses Enter and the state changes. But setting the `readonly` property solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the input from being edited in the keyUp event handler:

```
onKeyUp = (e) => {
   // Check if we still accept typing
   if (no_more_typing) return e.preventDefault();
   // Handle enter key
   if (e.keyCode === 13) onAnswer(e.target.value);
}

<input
  onKeyUp={onKeyUp} ...
```

Comment: Excuse me if I'm missing something but this isn't working for me. Initially I can enter some numbers and nothing happens until I press Enter key. Then the state is set -> it's OK until this moment but after I can still edit the input value. The code goes into the first `if` branch but it seems like `e.preventDefault()` does not prevent me from editing the value of the input field.
UPDATE: your solution works if I use `value` instead of `defaultValue` on the input but then it causes the same warning: `A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled.`

Comment: Could you try with `onKeyPress` instead of `onKeyUp`, this is what I use to filter out some characters that I don't want and it works

Comment: Regarding the warning, when you do `value=undefined`, it means that your input is uncontrolled (basically input is self managing its value). But then when you do `value={this.props.answer}`, then your input becomes controlled because you're imposing a value. Could you try `value = {this.props.answer || ''}`

Comment: `onKeyPress` does not work. There is no `e.keyCode`.

Comment: If I use `value = {this.props.answer || ''}` this is the warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Comment: with `onKeyPress` you can do: `if (event.key === 'Enter')`

Comment: If you set the value, then you must also have an onChange event handler, that's the way it is